# Delegate JS events to different objects

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, file-upload, jquery-events

I'm trying to re-skin the input type file element.

I do this by placing two elements on top of each other. One of them is the input tag and the other is a nice button. Something like this:

```
<input type="file" id="filesButton" multiple>
<input type="button" id="filesButtonOverlay" value="Add Files">
```

The button has some nice effects when a user hovers, clicks, etc (all done is CSS). However since the input-type-file has a higher z-index (needs to be the case since you can't emulate a click on it) all these effects don't show.

Is there a nice way to delegate all events that input-type-file gets and trigger them on the button?

Answer (score 0):

What if you wrapped the inputs in a div and attached the events to the div? Then target your button with your changes?

Comment: the event are mostly css or somewhere in twitter bootstrap, which I don't really want to change

Answer (score 0):

I would think you should be able to do this with a shared parent.  Then you place the `hover` on the parent rather than the button itself.

```
<span id="wrapper">
    <input type="file" id="filesButton" multiple>
    <input type="button" id="filesButtonOverlay" value="Add Files">
</span>
```

---

```
$("#wrapper").hover(function(){
    $("#filesButtonOverlay").dosomething();
});
```

or in CSS:

```
#wrapper:hover #filesButtonOverlay{
  stuff:
}
```

If you could potentially have multiple on the same page, you'd want to change to using classes instead of `id`s

Comment: I can also do that without the shared parent just instead of #wrapper have #filesButton but I'm looking for an elegant way to do this rather than having a listener for every different event

Comment: File inputs are pretty well protected by the browser.  I still don't think I understand your question, but I'm starting to think there is no solution due to security protections.